# Last tableview cell is cut off at bottom of view controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, cells

[image]

It seems as though the LAST cell is cut off. I'm not quite sure if the problem is that the cell is cut off, or the view controller isn't scrolling all the way down. I suppose they're the same problem however.

Not sure why this is going on.

Comment: Is this a `tableViewController`, or a `tableView` within a `viewController`?  Check its bottom constraint and make sure it's tied to the bottom layout guide, with no margin.  You also want to make sure its constant is 0.  Another reason you might see this is having a height constraint on the tableView.

Comment: @PetahChristian it's a view controller. I'll try those changes though.

Comment: Did you make any progress?  The top appears to be absent from the screenshot.  Is this view controller embedded in a navigation controller?  Is the table's top/content inset under those bars?  If something happens to be off by 64px, it's often related to the `contentInset` not being set properly.

Comment: Who know how to solve this problem ? i also got this problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with collection view.  Defining the following layout constraints(navigation bar on top) fixed the problem for me...

collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

Give it a try(replacing collectionView with tableView).  Good luck!